# Скачать партнерский xml себе на хостинг

Tags: php, xml, парсер

Подскажите, как с помощью php можно скачать получить файл XML поставщика себе на хостинг, просто скачать, ссылка не содержит расширения файла, но формат XML. Пробовал file_get_contents но не сработало.

ссылка на файл http://aquapolis.ua/export/get/file/id/for_partners/

Comment: И как оно нее сработало? вы смотрели результат в браузере, и он показал пустую страницу? посмотрите "код страницы"

Comment: где ваш код скачивания-то? убедитесь, что возможно открытие внешних ссылок, и запись в файл.

Comment: Извините, забыл передать то что скачал в put_contents ... Все работает) Я еще только учусь..